# PHP While Foreach of MySQL key

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

Search far and wide and couldn't find an answer so I thought it was time to post. I currently have a table of vendors. I would like to loop through each vendor using the 'skuid' value for each as it is unique, then echo other information from that row. Here's what I have so far.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
    exit();
}

$vendorQuery = "SELECT skuid FROM vendors";
$vendorResult = mysqli_query($mysqli, $vendorQuery);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vendorResult)) {
    foreach($row['skuid'] as $vendorid) {
        echo $row['skuid'];
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: `$row['skuid']` not an array.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need that `foreach`, your outer loop is enough

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vendorResult)) {
        echo $row['skuid'];
}
```

And a single mysql query doesn't return nested levels of data so there can't be any good use cases for a nested loop in this scenario.

When this loop runs, there is always only 1 `skuid` per row. There is no use for another nested loop there.

Now if you want to create an array of vendors from this query and then loop over it that's a good use case. For example

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vendorResult)) {
        $skuid=$row['skuid'];
        $name=$row['name'];
        $vendors[$skuid]=array('name'=>$name); // and other fields
}
foreach($vendors as $vendor){
        echo $vendor['name'];
}
```

Comment: Any idea why 

`
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
 if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
  exit();
 }
 
 $vendorQuery = "SELECT * FROM vendors";
 $vendorResult = mysqli_query($mysqli, $vendorQuery);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vendorResult)) {
  echo $row['first_name'];
 } ?>
`

Returns

**mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given**